# Differentiability at a point of a cuve

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves

I have to study the differentiability  of the following curve
$$\begin{array}{cccc} C: & [0, 2\pi ]& \longrightarrow & \mathbb{C} \\ 
& t & \longmapsto & r(t+i-ie^{-ti}) \end{array}$$ at the points $t=0$ and $t=2\pi$. 
Differentiating we obtain that
$$\begin{array}{cccc} C': & \mathbb{R} & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{C} \\ & t & \longmapsto &r\left( 1-e^{-ti}\right) \end{array}$$

My question is the following: is it enough to say that since
$$C^\prime (0)=0 $$ $$ C^\prime (2\pi)=0$$
the tangent vector is not well-defined, therefore the curve is not differentiable? 
If not, could anyone point me how to do it properly?

Comment: Consider the curve $y=x^2$ parametrized by $g(t)=(t^3,t^6)$. Of course, $g'(0)=(0,0)$. Of course, $g$ is a smooth function. Do we conclude that the "curve is not differentiable"?

Comment: @TedShifrin I see, in that case the curve would be differentiable. So my approach is wrong, how could I do it then?

Comment: Write down real and imaginary parts and graph this!